# Java Check If String Contains Specific Numeric Sequence

Tags: java

I have a method I created to check if a string contains any variation of nines in the String. This could be 4 nines, 9 nines etc. The problem I have is this will be true for anything with 9 in it. I need to pull a certain numeric sequence that can vary in length.

The reason I have to check for these nines is because of bad data. This bad data could have five nines or ten nines etc. 99999999 OR 999999999 and return true if found.

What would be a good way to accomplish what I'm looking to do? I am still learning. Thanks!

Here is what I had written for this method

```
 public static Boolean isValidTrmDt(String dt){


    if(dt.isEmpty() || dt == null || dt.equals("0") || dt.contains("9") == 
    true && dt.length() > 0) {



        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    return Boolean.TRUE;

}
```

Comment: Give example of which value have to return true, and which vqlue should return false, do you want to find full-9-sequence ?

Comment: "I have a method I created to check if a string contains 9. The problem I have is this will be true for anything with 9 in it." That sounds like... uhh... desirable behaviour, no?

Comment: `dt.isEmpty() || dt == null` If `dt` is null then this will throw a NullPointerException.  Check for null first --> `dt == null || dt.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I asked the question wrong. I need to return true if found 99999999, 99999999, 99999 or any other variation as long as it is 99. If it were say 1999 it would return false.

Comment: you need a negative lookbehind, "match a string if it has at least one time 9 not precedeed by another digit": something like ``String.matches("?![0-8]9+")`` (sorry not tested, but at least this is a direction)

Comment: Thanks, Spi! I think that's what I'm looking to do. I appreciate everybody who's chimed in on this so far. Sorry if the question was confusing. I will try better next time.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a regular expression

```
boolean oneOrMoreNines = myString.matches("9+");
```

See [String::matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)), and [test the regex](https://regex101.com/r/RRnqlY/2)

Comment: Is there a way to check two or more nines? For instance, if 1999 was inputted this would return false. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeZ Two or more nines is just `99+`. I don't know what you mean about `1999` - should it fail or succeed?

Comment: it would fail on 1999

Comment: Be aware that regex matching may be time and processing power consuming for very big and complex inputs

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your answer! I tested and this is working for my needs. I don't think the processing power should be a problem as I don't see the input being that big or complex.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly looks fine, but you have a lot of redundant checks.

```
dt.isEmpty() || dt == null || dt.equals("0") || dt.contains("9") == true && dt.length() > 0
```

Your `null` check should be first, otherwise `dt.isEmpty()` will throw an exception.

I'm not sure the point of `dt.length() > 0`. If it has a 9, its length is greater than zero already, because it has a 9.

You can simplify it to

```
dt == null || dt.isEmpty() || dt.equals("0") || dt.contains("9")
```

You can simplify it even further by just returning this statement:

```
public static boolean isValidTrmDt(String dt){
  return !(dt == null || dt.isEmpty() || dt.equals("0") || dt.contains("9"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if String only contains specific number use this method

```
boolean matchesNumber(String input, String numberToMatch){
    return input.replace(numberToMatch, "").isEmpty();
}
```